# JAXB mixed content list contains newline characters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I was hoping that you might be able to help me with a problem that I'm facing regarding JAXB.

I have the following XML file:

```
<root>
    <prop>
        <field1>
            <value1>v1</value1>
            <value2>v2</value2>
        </field1>
        <field2>
            <value1>v1</value1>
            <value2>v2</value2>
        </field2>
    </prop>
    <prop>
        text
        <field1>
            <value1>v1</value1>
            <value2>v2</value2>
        </field1>
    </prop>
    <prop>
        text
    </prop>
</root>
```

The XML can have under prop other elements (field1, field2), text or both.

And the following classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    protected List<Root.Element> prop;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Element {
        @XmlMixed
        protected List<String> content;
        @XmlElement
        public Field1 field1;
        @XmlElement
        public Field2 field2;

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public static class Field1 {
            @XmlElement
            protected String value1;
            @XmlElement
            protected String value2;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public static class Field2 {
            @XmlElement
            protected String value1;
            @XmlElement
            protected String value2;

        }

    }

}
```

I want to unmarshal the XML in to the above classes.
The issue that I'm having is that in the content list I get, besides the text, other characters like newline and tab. To be more specific, based on the above XML, when I try to unmarshal I get:

- first prop with content like ["\n\t\t", "\n\t\t", "\n\t"] - it should
  be an empty list
- second prop with content like ["\n\t\ttext\n\t\t",
  "\n\t"] - it should be a list with one string
- third prop with content
  like ["\n\t\ttext\n\t"] - it should be an empty list

I have already tried to create and a XMLAdapter but it is applied for every element in the list, so if I remove the \n and \t and return null if it is an empty string I still get a list with some strings and some null values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Why It's Happening

White space content in an element that has mixed context is treated as significant.

### How to Fix It

You could use JAXB with StAX to support this use case.  With StAX you can create a filtered `XMLStreamReader` so that any character strings that only contain white space are not reported as events.  Below is an example of how you could implement it.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("src/forum22284324/input.xml"));
        xsr = xif.createFilteredReader(xsr, new StreamFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader reader) {
                if(reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS) {
                    return reader.getText().trim().length() > 0;
                } 
                return true;
            }

        });

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

}
```